How can I reliably test the bandwidth through proxychains?
I run my proxychains through a modified SOCKS proxy, although that’s probably not relevant.
But I’ve been struggling to find a reliable way to test the upload/download speed through my proxychains.
Pinging (obviously) won’t help as I already know my latency.
I know of many installable tools for such testing, but I want to know if anyone knows a way of doing this without any extra tools?
PS there is no tag for proxychains so maybe someone should make one?
